# will_paginate function not rendering page links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, will-paginate

What I am trying to achieve is to paginate a huge number of rows (~8000). So I am using

```
@extractedpacks = ExtractedPack.all.paginate :page => params[:page],
  :per_page=>20, :order => 'id DESC'
```

To paginate in controller

**In the view index.html.erb**

```
<% @extractedpacks.each do |news| %>
<tr>
<td><%= news.name %></td>
<td><%= news.acted_upon %></td>
<td><%= news.crawl_category %></td>
<td><%= link_to action_generator(news.crawl_category, news), @actionurl %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
</table>
<%= will_paginate @extractedpacks %>
```

I have put in my gem file

```
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.0'
```

I ve put in config/application.rb (after a few browsing on stackoverflow)

```
require 'will_paginate'
```

Please help.. let me know if you need any other information..

**For your note.. :**

extractedpacks is definitely working..!!

I am getting first 20 rows if I didnt use `<%= will_paginate @extracted packs %>` in the view.. 
if I try to manually increase the page number like

```
localurl?page=2
```

then it works..

The exact problem is that will_paginate is not rendering the pages..

Comment: Change a little bit @extractedpacks = ExtractedPack.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30).order('id DESC')

Comment: @Debadatt : doesnt seem to work that way too..! :-(

Comment: @Debadatt : the pagination actually happens... but the problem lies with the link renderer..

Comment: Means normally after clicking page link nothing happening?

Comment: try this in your GemFile.... gem 'will_paginate', :git => "https://github.com/p7r/will_paginate.git", :branch => "rails3"

Comment: @Debadatt : actually the page loads with displaying first 20 records. The problem is that I dont get the links even after putting <%= will_paginate /@extractedpacks %> in the view. If I manually pass the parameter in url like url/?page=2 , I get the second page loading with next 20 records. the problem is just that the page links that are to be automatically generated, they are not generating..

Comment: @beck03076, I ve tried that beck.. Its not working. I also altered the config/application.rb by putting a require statement below. doesnt help

Comment: @MohammedAshiq: Have you checked the links in firebug? May be some css overrides the links. Open the firebug , see whether the htmls for links are being generated or not.

Comment: @Debadatt : thanks for your reply. Css does overrides the links but the link itself is not rendering.. I am getting an error which says will_paginate function is not found if I put <%= will_paginate \@extractedpacks %> in the view. which means that I the pagination works but the links to the next page is not rendering.. temporarily I ve put a next and previous link.. so that when i click that page get incremented/decremented manually. but this slows down my team's productivity. I need the links which says 1|2|3|.....|last|. For checking I tried removing css too as per your advice..!!