# will_paginate doesn't show links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

Before posting this question i tried this solution from a similar question here:
[will_paginate function not rendering page links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484278/will-paginate-function-not-rendering-page-links)

Instead of <- 1 2 3 ... N ->, I see the message "Fetching more products...".

**// controller** 
 1. @posts are ActiveRecord::Relation 
 2. 6 record as results, so expecting 3 pages

```
@posts = User.joins(entries: [{storage: :vote}, :category])
             .where("votes.count > ?", 0)
             .select("users.username AS username,
                       storages.id AS storage_id,
                       storages.title AS title, 
                       storages.content AS content, 
                       votes.count AS votes, 
                       categories.category_name AS category_name")
             .order("votes.count DESC")

@posts = @posts.page(params[:page]).per_page(2)
```

**// view**

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
   ...
   ...
<%end%>
<%= will_paginate @posts %>
```

For `http://localhost:3000/?page=1` i see "Fetching more products..."
for `http://localhost:3000/?page=2` also "Fetching more products..." 
but for `http://localhost:3000/?page=3` i see ← Previous 1 2 3 Next →.
Why pagination only on last page?

I'm using RoR 4.0.0

```
Gemfile: gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.5'
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be

@posts = @posts.paginate(params[:page], per_page: 2)

for quick look
http://skatara.blogspot.com/2015/02/pagination-in-rails-using-willpaginate.html